# Loading Partial view in ajaxified way

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am trying to load a partialview using ajax method. Since I have tried it in past but I don't know why this time it is not loading the content and data. I am wondering that where I am wrong. How can I correct this?

This is my view having partial view in one of its div named "Add_Group".

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("AddEditGroupWindow")
    .Title("Edit Group")
    .Content(@<text><div id="Add_Group" style="display:none; width:100%;">
            @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Admin/Views/UserGroups/_AddGroupPartial.cshtml");
        </div> </text>)
                .Visible(false).Width(1000).Height(300))
```

After I get data using post as below I am trying to load that patial view using 
below:

```
$.post("/UserGroups/getGroupDetail", { "groupId": id }, function (response) {
            $("#Add_Group").html(response.Data);
            $("#AddEditGroupWindow").data("kendoWindow").open();
            $("#Add_Group").show();
        });
```

in controller it is like below:

```
 public ActionResult GetGroupDetail(string groupId)
        {
            var data = string.Empty;
            UserGroupRoleModel objmodel = new UserGroupRoleModel();
            var groupEntity = this._userGroupServices.GetGroupDetail(Convert.ToInt32(groupId));
            return this.Json(new { Data = groupEntity });
        }
```

Comment: as you are doing a post ajax request decorate `GetGroupDetail` action with `HttpPost` attribute.

Comment: It is working fine and even return results. But div containing partial view is showing Empty. The problem is in just showing the partial view and loading the partial view. The C# is working fine and returing the correct results as Json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a json object by the post method, not html, hence when you call

`$("#Add_Group").html(response.Data);`

it display nothing, because `Data` is json not html

Your `GetGroupDetail` need to return html for it to show.

By the look of your code, I am assuming what you are returning from  `GetGroupDetail` is the model for the partial view ( `~/Areas/Admin/Views/UserGroups/_AddGroupPartial.cshtml`), change your `GetGroupDetail` to return partial view

```
public ActionResult GetGroupDetail(string groupId)
        {
            var data = string.Empty;
            UserGroupRoleModel objmodel = new UserGroupRoleModel();
            var groupEntity = this._userGroupServices.GetGroupDetail(Convert.ToInt32(groupId));
            return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/UserGroups/_AddGroupPartial.cshtml", roupEntity);
        }
```